# А можно ли сделать на сайте с WooCommerce конвертер чтобы можно было бы принимать платежи в валюте через Яндекс-кассу?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, конвертация, яндекс-касса

Всем привет!
Согласно оф. документации Яндекс-касса умеет принимать платежи только в рублях. Однако, есть необходимость прикрутить эту кассу к магазину, рассчитанному на ино. потребителей. Сайт на Woocommerce. Подскажите можно ли организовать конвертацию валют таким образом, чтобы при выборе товара с ценой в USD в окошке Яндекс-кассы высвечивалась та же сумма (например, товар стоит 5 USD  и в окошке кассы указано значение 5$)?

Comment: Что за странные идеи. Яндекс-касса не примет валютный платёж. Вам нужна другая платёжная система для платежей в валюте.

Comment: Не буду с вами спорить, но техподдержка яндекса сказала что  с Яндекс-кассой можно проделать такой трюк если при этом организовать конвертацию валют на сайте. Однако после конвертации в окошке кассы будет стоять сумма в рублях. А мне бы хотелось чтобы она была в USD